# Django: How can I create a function in models to get the username that made that post and also in views

Tags: python, django, view, model, backend

I am creating a forum and i’ve been paralized with this problem, i can’t create a model to get the username of the user that made a post in the forum, i made a search and found nothing hope someone can help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you want to do. If you share your code I would be able to help more

I believe is possible to solve your problem by creating a foreign key for User in your model post (considering your post is a model and has a foreignk in the model forum)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=WHATEVER YOU DECIDE)
```

Then you could access using this

```
forum = Forum.objects.get(id=1)
for post in forum.posts_set.all():
    print(post.user.username)
```